# Setting message in tableviewer cell

Tags: eclipse, jface, rcp, tableviewer

Is there any method that sets message to tableviewer cell, like

```
setMessage(String message)
```

for Text widget, where the message would vanish upon entering a value.

Comment: This is something you should be able to craft in the label provider.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to achieve it.